# In Blazor serverside can you get hold of circuit specific state in a static context without passing it in?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Ok, a rather specific question which requires additional explanation and context.

*Context*

We are POCing a "try-convert" from a bespoke language to .net core (5 currently) and blazor server. Server because it allows a try-convert scaffolding we can build security concerns round. The details of this are not important. It just explains why we have some constraints which may seem unrealistic under normal circumstances.

I am fully accepting that "no you can't" or even "no you shouldn't" is the likely outcome. We are exploring possibilities.

*Question*

The concept of a circuit in blazor is a really good fit for the presentation layer. We would like to store information at the scope of the circuit.

The obvious solution is to use a scoped service in the dependency injection container.

E.g. In my Startup.cs I can put

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddScoped<IStaticStore, ClientStaticStorage>();
}
```

This allows me to store information which in my original (pre-converted) application was static scoped to a desktop, but in blazor server side is a fake "static" store scoped to the circuit. IStaticStore and ClientStaticStorage are just classes I have created - dictionaries of data I can access.

*Crux*

Can we access the circuit scoped data in a static method (or property) without passing it in?

If I was in a razor component we could @inject it in and access it from an instanced context

But clearly accessing from a static is going to make the compiler complain that an object reference is required

```
@inject IStaticStore StaticStore    

@code {
    static void DoSomeThing()
    {
        var thingy = StaticStore.InternalGetStatic<Thing>("foo", "bar");           
    }
}
```

In reality I am not wanting to access from the razor component - clearly here the answer would be pass the store around. I am accessing in c# code way down the stack and converted across from 20 years of grown functionality (hence I have a complex strange situation).

So - can I access StaticStore here, from the circuit scope in a nice simple static friendly helper way without passing it into the static method.

The closest example I can think of is how you used to be able to access HttpContext.Current (pre .net core) and it magically it gave you the scoped httpcontext. Is there anything similar for a circuit?

Comment: I have to confess, that's a lot of words, and it's hard for me to understand what you want to do.  If you have a static class, why don't you make it a Scoped DI service instead?  A service can definitely inject another service.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Ha - yeh, that's a very good point (too many words). I'll do a tldr; There is a single simple question in there - it's just the reason for asking it is complex. Let me split it up. I think I'll probably answer it too (with a no), then the answer can be challenged.

Comment: @Jonny Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @user3071284 - The answer as far as I know at the moment to the question is "no" - the circuit scope stuff (in services.AddScoped in the example above) is not available unless passed. The solution to my problem was to refactor. In reality this gave me a more sustainable end solution so was worth the investment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood both your question and the Blazor concepts, the answer to your question is « no ». There is no possibility to retrieve statically the current HTTP context in Blazor. Because you never know if the context is an initial page load or just SignalR communication to update the current page.
Here is the manner I save this situation:

- Create a cascading parameter that is shared by all razor components
- This cascading parameter is a class with many information coming from
  initial HTTP request, caught in the _Host.cshtml from the
  httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
- This cascading parameter class gets all the methods of my previous
  static methods.
- These methods can use the properties of the cascading parameter:
  RawUrl, UserAgent, ClientIp, …

This implies hard refactoring work to migrate legacy ASP web sites. But the performances of Blazor are worth it.

Comment: This is a good answer. I don't actually want anything off HttpContext - just used it as an example of how HttpContext.Current magically did something akin to what I wanted. It was removed from the language because it's not a great pattern, so I'm guessing they are not going to re-introduce a "magic" static for circuit scope. I can't think of anyway round it other than refactor and hard work - not always a bad thing.